# Explain how a reflected XSS payload gets echoed from an HTTP request to an HTML document

Tags: security, xss

Explain how a reflected XSS payload gets echoed from an HTTP request to an HTML document.

I could use some help

Answer (score 0):

Reflexive XSS payloads are about a user input that was not sanitized correctly and now you can inject some code.

Suppose we have a website `vulnerable.com` and there you have a search bar, you can search for blog posts. If you search for `bar foo` the result page is rendered and there you have written: `12 results for bar foo`, your input was **reflected** on the page and this is the first step to find a reflexive XSS.

Now what? If you try to search `<script>alert(1)</script>`, will it be reflected on the page? If it does you get an alert from the browser saying `1` and you found a reflexive XSS, congratulations! Otherwise, it could be sanitized, ways of doing it is substituting the `<` and `>` for avoiding inserting a new HTML tag like `script`.

Basically what happened is that your input was sent to the server and they built a page using your input then they sent it back to you as the response for your request.

Some links for helping:

[OWASP XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Types_of_Cross-Site_Scripting#Reflected_XSS_.28AKA_Non-Persistent_or_Type_II.29)

[PortSwigger](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting)